# Who has EKF filter open source code?

Tags: c++, filter, quaternions

I have been working on IMU sensors to get orientation and I am looking for an open source EKF filter! Or please share ur expertise if anyone has experience!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The [help/on-topic] guidelines very clearly say *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading those [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with how this site works and what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before posting again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took on the same task this summer with a [flight-path interpreter](https://github.com/nolanholden/geovis). Check out my implementation of the linear filter [here](https://github.com/nolanholden/geovis/blob/master/src/geovis/kalman.h#L37).

It looks like researchers believe the EKF [yields less reliable estimates without some *complicated* mitagtion techniques](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4543252/?reload=true&arnumber=4543252). For measurement that are changing very rapidly (unlike GPS navigation where EKF is indeed a de facto standard), consider avoiding the EKF. According to that paper, the ongoing-estimate can diverge pretty quickly.